# I need help understanding a piece code

Tags: python-2.7

I would really appreciate If someone could help me understand it thanks p.s. Im new to code

```
sentence = "I like my dog I buy my dog toys"
s = sentence.split()
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
print(sentence)
print(positions)
```

I would really appreciate If someone could help me understand it thanks p.s. Im new to code

Comment: read about list comprehensions and string manipulation.

Comment: This just prints the location of the first occurrence of each word in the list (`s.index(x)+1`)

Answer (score 2):

Jean is correct. Have you done any online python tutorials?
Here goes.
The first line assigns the string "I like my dog I buy my dog toys" to a variable named sentence.

the next line

```
s = sentence.split()
```

breaks up the string into an array of substrings and assigns that array to variable s

```
>>> print(s)
['I', 'like', 'my', 'dog', 'I', 'buy', 'my', 'dog', 'toys']
```

the next line

```
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
```

looks for the occurrence of each of each array value and logs its position to the array position

```
>>> print(positions)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 3, 4, 9]
```

**EDIT**

Allow me to elaborate on some key points. First, the split function. Many languages have a split function. They all take a delimiter, the character upon which the string will be split. In Python, the split() function can be called with no delimiter. In this case the function will use a single space character (" "). Thus when we call sentence.split(), it takes the value of the sentence variable and breaks it apart using the single space and returns an array of the various substrings, or pieces. In this case the individual words.

Next, let's look at the line

```
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
```

Let's consider the following for a moment

```
for x in s
  i = s.index(x)
```

this is a basic loop that takes each item in array s and places it in variable x. The first pass through this loop takes "I" and assigns it to x. Then we look for the position of "I" in the array of s. Since s contains the words od the sentence in order, the first position, array item 0 contains the value "I". So, the value of variable i becomes 0. The loop continues matching each item in array s and finds the value's corresponding position within the array.

Taking this one step further, we instantiate another array, in this case position. As the loop iterates over the array s finding the corresponding indices of each value, those positions are then placed in the new array position.

Now most people do not necessarily think in terms of zero based lists. Therefore, we take an extra step and add 1 to each position as it is found. So position 0 becomes position 1, and so on.

So what is different about the for loop I used to demonstrate above and the single line of code used in the example of this question? Nothing really. this line

```
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
```

is simply a condensed form of the for loop. In Python, this is known as List Comprehension.

At this point, this answer is becoming more of a small instructional on Python. I really need to suggest that you seek out and find some tutorials on Python, starting with the one on [Pythons documentation site](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). Another one may be here on [TutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/), or [Learn Python](http://www.learnpython.org/). There are also great resources on Pluralsite and Cousera as well.

Good luck

Comment: Is it possible to go into further detail, sorry to be a hassle

Comment: Could you please explain sub-strings and the occurrence of each of each array value. Thanks